# React-router <NavLink> component doesn't get active after click on it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Here's the code of the component where I use `<NavLink>` from `react-router-dom` library. After I click on it and url changes to once specified in `to` prop the styles I specify in `activeStyle` prop don't appear as it supposed to.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import styles from './../../styles/components/ListLabel.css'

class ListLabel extends Component {
  render() {
    const { name, id } = this.props

    return (
      <NavLink
        to={`/list/${id}`}
        style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'inherit' }}
        activeStyle={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}
      >
        <div className={styles['list-label']}>
          <div className={styles['name']}>
            {this.props.name}
          </div>
          <i className={styles['settings-button']} />
        </div>
      </NavLink>
    )
  }
}

export default ListLabel
```

Here's the route:

```
<Content>
  <Route path="/list/:listId" component={ListContent} />
</Content>
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: the `divs` inbetween your `NavLink` and the actual text you're trying to style is likely the problem. Looks like they're also applying styles of their own. You want the text you're styling to be as close to the `<NavLink>` sandwich as possible.

Comment: Yea, I thought about that. Tried to use plain text instead of those `div`s and it was no difference.

Comment: You had `<NavLink to="/route" activeStyle={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>Hi</NavLink>` and nothing happened?

Comment: Exactly. By the way the `<Route>` works fine, it renders corresponding component like it has to.

Comment: Did you fix it? Same problem here!